# Unable to get the HTTP Post request correct C#

Tags: c#, http-post, http-status-code-401

I am using Oauth 1.0 for authentication process. I am stuck at the very first step for getting the request token. Executing the following request throws  **'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'**

```
        Uri uri1 = new Uri("https://api.500px.com/v1/oauth/request_token");
        string consumerKey = "ABFHGHIQYW4clmuXXXXXXXBy528gl2zEEEEN";
        string consumerSecret = "BBGHGJnrJaKKjoScCFHJGJFKK6HVjjDHFJSDJDjno";
        string timeStamp = myOAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string nonce = myOAuth.GenerateNonce();
        myOAuth.includeVersion = true;
        string signature = myOAuth.GenerateSignature(uri1, consumerKey, consumerSecret, "", "", "POST", timeStamp, nonce, OAuth.OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.500px.com/v1/oauth/request_token");           
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_callback=\"http://www.abcxyz.com\",oauth_consumer_key=\"" +consumerKey + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" +nonce + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=" + signature);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

All the parameters are passed through 'Authorization Header' of HTTP Post. I am definitely missing something in my request but unable to figure it out exactly what is missing.

Any pointers or any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add first need a request to get token. After that create another request and pass token as parameter.

Comment: My above request is for getting that very 'request token' which is throwing 401 error which means my request is malformed.